# Unwanted Margin in Layout with TabHost

Tags: android-layout, android-tabhost

I'm relativity new to Android development, but I do like to think I catch on fast.  I've been re-working an app I made for my softball team. Previously I've used Google's App Inventor, but have run into many shortcomings with it, so I am now attempting to re-work it using Eclipse.

Anyway, to the point. I seem to be having some excess padding being added to my LinearLayout, which I'm not sure where it is coming from.

I am using the TabHost to create the tabs on top (a modified version of Google's Tabs example).

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/main_linlay_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >

    <TabHost 
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                >        

                <!-- Allow the "Tabs" to scroll horizontally -->
                <HorizontalScrollView 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                    android:fillViewport="true" 
                    android:scrollbars="none" 
                    >

                    <!-- The "Tabs" widget -->
                    <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:background="#000000"
                        />

                </HorizontalScrollView>

                <!-- Provide the "Content" the ability to vertically scroll -->
                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
                    >
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        >
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/tabdata"
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                             >
                         </LinearLayout>
                    </FrameLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

I believe the issue has to with the `android:layout_marginTop="65dp"` in the ScrollView, but if I remove it, my Tabs disappear (I'm assuming my tabcontent is just being overlayed over the top of it).

Lastly, here's a screen shot showing an example of what I'm experiencing (Disreguard the XML string, I still need to massage that part. I just wanted to show an example with data.).
http://kahunaball.com/android/screenshot_0.jpg

Answer (score 0):

After starting the XML over from scratch and taking small steps forward, I was able to re-work the XML and resolve the excess padding from my layout.

I'm not 100% sure which change made the difference, but my suspicions are that changing the `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` and moving the `LinearLayout` and `TableLayout` outside of the `FrameLayout` were what had done the trick.

For others that may stumble across this and would like to see my new XML which resolved the issue, here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background">
        <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">
            <TabWidget 
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000000" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <HorizontalScrollView 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:fillViewport="true" 
                android:scrollbars="none" >
                <FrameLayout 
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tabdata"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#33B5E5" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </ScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```